# Socket called on wrong port

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets, glassfish-4

I am having a web server running glass fish 4  on port 8080 in my local. I am also having a standalone java socket server running in local on port 9010.

When I try to access a webservice from Objective C on my glass fish server using NSURLConnection on port 8080, the socket also gets called even though it runs on a different port.
NSURL connection code is provided below,

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:”http://localhost:8080/testapp/customer/authenticate”]];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@“post”];
[request setHTTPBody:myjsonRequestData];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I have searched but could not find any leads. Please help

Comment: Please post your NSURLConnection code

Comment: I have updated the question with NSURLConnection code

Comment: Sorry this is a coding bug in my server code and other tied issues in the client code. My interpretation was wrong. I have solved it now.

Comment: Please post this as an answer so the question can get marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is a coding bug in my server code and other tied issues in the client code. My interpretation was wrong. I have solved it now.